# How do I download the whole Projects Docs in Github as Pdf?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

How do I download the whole Projects Docs in Github as Pdf or notepad? Example clicking on this link, I would like to download whole Nunit project docs. Right now, I am only able to read by clicking on each page 1 by 1. Would like to save whole file and print out.

https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseData

[image]

Using solution below, we see error as reported by many users

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Unknown language: "C#" –
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [Github Wikito Converter](https://github.com/yakivmospan/github-wikito-converter):

1. `npm install -g github-wikito-converter`
2. `git clone https://github.com/nunit/docs.wiki.git`
3. `gwtc ./docs.wiki`

Comment: last step I received this error Unhandled rejection Error: Unknown language: "C#"

Comment: I tried it with another wiki repo and it works great, now I tried with nunit wiki and I got the same error :/

Comment: @HardyWest Great :) maybe need open an issue also in https://github.com/yakivmospan/github-wikito-converter/issues